# Moving binary files between big endian and little endian platforms

Tags: networking, cpu-architecture, endianness

I know that network byte order is big endian regardless of host endianness.

My question is what happens when a binary file is moved from a BE to LE platform.
From this post I can see the data byte order on disk is the same as memory byte order of the platform:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751824

So assume I have a small binary file on a LE machine with this content in LE order `2 5`:
(Note I have turned this into an actual binary file with `xxd`)

```
00000010 00000101
```

- Use `wget` to download this file on a BE machine.
- Checkout the file content and it's still `00000010 00000101`.

Didn't the file had to be reversed to `00000101 00000010` before transmission? If so
would't the BE machine store it as is in network order after it has received it? How is the file content not reversed after download?

Comment: network byte order is network byte order, it is not big endian nor little endian.  It is network byte order.   Then you have how the peripheral maps that packet data into the address space of the processor or copies the data into a memory somewhere.  then there is the architecture and access type/size.  then there are at least different definitions of the term big endian and you can very much have big endian not access the network byte order data in the way that you are thnking 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44 in the network stream can be 0x11223344 or 0x44332211 in big endian depending on processor...

Comment: Using and trying to isolate things into endian buckets tends to cause more pain that success.  Instead do your system engineering.  How does the data come into the peripheral, how is it or can it be presented to the processor, what are the processors access options/features via modes or instructions, etc.   The term endian is not needed for any of this.

Comment: files are files, just like the above statements, one thing has nothing to do with the other, files are a sequence of bits or bytes, a proper transfer will copy the file through whatever medium (network, wireless, hard disk to thumb drive, optical drives, etc) to the hard drive/ssd of some other machine, independent of operating system, operating system version, file system type, architecture of the processor, etc.

Comment: The physical interface of networking itself is not fixed, each technology has one if not more than one way of chopping the bits up sending them across the media and then putting them back together, there are multiple layers just within the physical layer not counting the textbook network layers themselves that are also involved.  Then on top of those network layers you have file layers and operating system etc, to insure the file, ideally, shows up bit for bit the same.

Comment: Then it is the programmers job, ideally not using the term endian, to read/write the files.  Do your system engineering, dont just assume BE or LE means anything relevant, because it does not.  commiting the cardinal sin of using structs across compile domains leads to the endian problems.  Can be easily avoided and endianless if desired and more portable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is what happens when a binary file is moved from a BE to LE platform.

The file bytes should be copied without being swapped at all — the bytes should appear in the same order on all machines, as elaborated byte by byte.

For simple text it doesn't matter, since sequences of individual bytes are not endian in nature.

For most anything else, there will be a defined file format, which specifies the endianness of numeric fields larger than 8 bits.  This is what you have already observed about TCP/IP, which defines big endian for the headers.

JPG, PNG, others either avoid multi-byte numerics or define how the bytes in the file are interpreted when multi-byte numeric values are employed.

Certain data formats will use a Byte Order Mark [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is part of a flexible format that allows the writer to choose endianness (so can choose the one that is natural for the writing system, if desired), and, this allows reader to determine the endianness of the file.

For multi-byte text, Unicode uses some of the above features, but the more modern encoding, UTF-8, is supposed to be interpreted as "simple" sequence of bytes (rather than multi-byte numbers) and doesn't need a BOM or notion of endianness.

Comment: Thanks so I edited my question to make it even more clear,  I used `xxd` to convert this to an actual binary file. So I'm literally transmitting a 2 byte binary file. There are no headers or metadata, literally just 2 bytes.

Comment: @Dan, my answer applies to any file, whether 0, 1, 2, or more bytes in size.

Comment: So I guess without any header or metadata, my file is being treated as a simple text file and not being swapped?

Comment: With or without header, the bytes should be copied in the same order they appear on the source machine.  It is the file formats that determines how bytes look on the disc.  (Or network formats that determine how they look on the wire.)  It is up to the reading system (and also the writing system) to adhere to the specifications.

Comment: If there are no headers and my raw binary file is being transferred in big endian order, how does the recipient know what to do with it? is utf8? is it binary? do I just store it as is? the file was originally in LE format on the host, does it get sent over in LE format in this case?

Comment: In the abstract, they don't know what to do with it.  But if they know the file format, the will use that format's specification to interpret the file data.

Comment: and what if they don't know the format (in my case)? So, 1- would the host machine send the data over in BE format or in its current LE format?  2- Would the end machine store the data on disk as it receives it or would it byte swap it?

Comment: There is no such thing as BE format or LE format.  What will happen is that bytes are copied in the order they appeared originally.  Can a receiver of a file not know the format?  Yes, of course.  Try to open an .mp3 with an image viewer, you'll get either garbage or an error.

Comment: This is kind of confusing. If data get sent over as they are on disk, then when does the "network byte order" kick in?

Comment: Network byte order is the definition of how multi-byte numeric values in the headers of TCP/IP packets must appear on the wire.  It doesn't say how the payload must appear, that is usually in a (well-defined) file format.

Comment: Ah so not EVERYTHING will be transmitted in network order? Most parts of a file will be transferred as they are on host, and the parts that get swapped (numeric values) will be known to the receiver based on the file meta data?

Comment: That is correct, the payload contents will be on the wire according to some file format, like text or JPG, which, if needed specifies its own definitions of fields and byte order.  Headers prepended to the payload are in network (big) byte endian order.

Comment: If you were going to byte swap, you'd have to know a very lot about the content.  Byte swapping is wrong for byte sequences, and for words you have to know the word size (2,4,8,16..).  So we don't attempt byte swapping in the abstract.  Headers and payloads are shared using their own independent specifications.

Comment: And just wanted to confirm, if there is no specific file format or header or metadata like in my case, content just gets sent over as is without any swapping and host stores it as is?

Comment: Yes, bytes of one file are sent to the other computer as if one-by-one, to store as a file of bytes in the same sequence on both machines.  It is up to the applications to interpret the file's format properly in general, and if that means byte swapping because there is a mismatch then the application has to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is organized as a sequence of bytes on both endians, so where data is merely a sequence of bytes, as for instance ASCII or UTF8, there is no problem. The problems start when groups of 2 or 4 or 8 bytes are interpreted as numbers, at which point you need to define whether the first or last byte in a group is the least significant. That is the difference between big and little endian.

If you represent text in UTF-16, where text is coded as a sequence of 2-byte values, then endianness matters, and in fact part of UTF-16 is a zero width non breaking space inserted at the start to indicate the byte order.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention this isn't text. I used `xxd` to convert this to an actual binary file. So I'm literally transmitting a 2 byte binary file. You didn't really answer my question tho.

Comment: @Dan: If you use `xxd` properly, the file *won't* get byte-swapped or otherwise messed up.

Comment: @PeterCordes it didn't actually, I learned from the answer above that not every transmission is done with bytes in BE order.